# select element using tag and attribute selector Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-factory

I want to add and remove css class on HTML elements in Angular controller, but i am using `jQuery` code for this and the code is :

```
$("li").children("a[ui-sref]").parent().removeClass("active");       
$("li").children("a[ui-sref='."+nextTab+"']").parent().addClass("active");
```

But now i want to use [angular element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) for this selection of element how can i achieve?

Comment: you need to utilize ng-if directive for this, please read the doc of it and do proper use, that's it.

Comment: any other option excluding `ng-if`?

Comment: Yes, you can make your own custom directives like as class, element or attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-class

```
ng-class="{'active':active ,'in-active',!active}"
```